# i18next backend load resources depending on detected language js

Tags: javascript, express, i18next

I want to load resources depending on a detected language by i18next-express-middleware library. Could you please tell how to properly make it?
I have an idea to make a request to an endpoint and after make an i18next initialization, but it seems a wrong way.

I have the following code:

```
import express from 'express';
import i18next from "i18next";
import middleware from "i18next-express-middleware";
import manifestHelpers from 'express-manifest-helpers';
import Backend from 'i18next-node-remote-backend';

i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .use(middleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    ns: 'common',
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'https://site/localization/{{ns}}?lang={{lng}}'
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(i18next.getResourceBundle('uk', 'common')) // undefined
  });

const app = express();

app.use(middleware.handle(i18next));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.language); // uk
  req.store = configureStore();
  return next();
});
```

Comment: What your going to translate?  Your response ?

Comment: I have an endpoint with 3 namespaces(home/services/about) and lang query param which can accept either en, de or fr. I need somehow to fetch resources from this endpoint based on user request language. And if user changes his language, either from url(site/fr) or using UI, I should make a new request. Also I should stick a rule with the following priority for redirection: URL > Cookies  > Accept Language.